# Out of Index Error when reading Image with OpenCV using Pointer

Tags: opencv, rgb, 16-bit, imread

I receive a weird out of range error when reading an 16-bit RGB image with openCV. The image has a resolution of 2700 x 2000. Outer rows and columns of the image are black.

I got the following code:

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    // Create Mat Container and rowPtr
    Mat image;
    image = imread(argv[1], -1);
    uint16_t* rowPtr;

    // Read Image characteristics
    int width = image.cols;
    int height = image.rows;
    int numChannels = image.channels();


    if (image.isContinuous())
    {
        std::cout << "isContinuous!" << "\n";
        width *= height;
        height = 1;

    }


    // Double for loop, reading using pointers according to
    // https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/core/how_to_scan_images/how_to_scan_images.html
    for ( uint32_t y = 0; y < height; ++y )
    {
        rowPtr = image.ptr<uint16_t>(y); 

        for ( uint32_t x = 0; x < width; ++x )
        {
            const uint32_t idx = x + y * width;

        // Quick Debug
            if (idx > 2704713)
            {
                std::cout << "height : " << height << "\n";
                std::cout << "width : " << width << "\n";
                std::cout << "row : " << y << "\n";
                std::cout << "col : " << x << "\n";
                std::cout << "idx : " << idx << "\n";
                std::cout << "B: " << rowPtr[numChannels * idx + 0] << "\n";
                std::cout << "G: " << rowPtr[numChannels * idx + 1] << "\n";
                std::cout << "R: " << rowPtr[numChannels * idx + 2] << "\n"; //The error occurs here!
            }          
        }
    }
    namedWindow( "Display window", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );    // Create a window for display.
    imshow( "Display window", image );                   // Show our image inside it.
    waitKey(0);                                          // Wait for a keystroke in the window
    return 0;
}
```

The output of running the code is:

```
isContinuous!
height : 1
width : 5400000
row : 0
col : 2704714
idx : 2704714
B: 0
G: 0
```

So, the segmentation fault happens, when the value for R should be read, at Pixel No. 2,704,715.

This code runs without problems for images that don't exhibit large black borders.  So I thought that openCV's imread  might crop such images internally, leading to such an error?

Comment: What format is your image stored in? And how do you know it's 16 bit? Did you check the number of channels?

Comment: NumChannel is 3. I just recognized that the image is an 8-bit RGB one. Using a 16-bit png works. Thanks for that hint. Can you explain why that is happening?

Comment: If you take twice as many bytes as you actually have for each pixel, you will run out sooner than you expect and *"go off the end"* of your data.

Comment: allright thanks alot!